# Nested Grouping with Muenchian method

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I have a static data-set in XML that has various data which is all relational. I am attempting to re-sort the data in reverse into a *UL list* while skipping the entries that do not lead up to.

**Dataset:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <landmarks>
        <entry id="9932">
            <landmark-name>Statue of Liberty</landmark-name>
            <linked-city link-id="432">New York</linked-city>
        </entry>
        <entry id="3020">
            <landmark-name>WTC</landmark-name>
            <linked-city link-id="432">New York</linked-country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="5829">
            <landmark-name>Times Square</landmark-name>
            <linked-city link-id="432">New York</linked-country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="2348">
            <landmark-name>Eiffel Tower</landmark-name>
            <linked-city link-id="932">Paris</linked-country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="2348">
            <landmark-name>Hollywood</landmark-name>
            <linked-city link-id="458">Los Angeles</linked-country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="4592">
            <landmark-name>Museo Nacional de Antropología</landmark-name>
            <linked-city link-id="328">Mexico City</linked-country>
        </entry>
    </landmarks>
    <cities>
        <entry id="432">
            <city-name>New York</city-name>
            <linked-country link-id="21">United States</linked-country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="458">
            <city-name>Los Angeles</city-name>
            <linked-country link-id="21">United States</linked-country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="832">
            <city-name>Miami</city-name>
            <linked-country link-id="21">United States</linked-country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="932">
            <city-name>Paris</city-name>
            <linked-country link-id="58">France</linked-country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="392">
            <city-name>Nice</city-name>
            <linked-country link-id="58">France</linked-country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="328">
            <city-name>Mexico City</city-name>
            <linked-country link-id="2">Mexico</linked-country>
        </entry>
    </cities>
    <countries>
        <entry id="21">
            <country>United States</country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="42">
            <country>Canada</country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="2">
            <country>Mexico</country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="58">
            <country>France</country>
        </entry>
        <entry id="23">
            <country>Spain</country>
        </entry>
    </countries>
</data>
```

**Desired Outcome:**

```
<ul>
    <li>United States
        <ul>
            <li>New York
                <ul>
                    <li>Statue of Liberty</li>
                    <li>Times Square</li>
                    <li>WTC</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Los Angeles
                <ul>
                    <li>Hollywood</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>France
        <ul>
            <li>Paris
                <ul>
                    <li>Eiffel Tower</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Mexico
        <ul>
            <li>Mexico City
                <ul>
                    <li>Museo Nacional de Antropología</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to be able to group the data from the aspect of "landmarks" meaning first we get all the landmarks and then see which city they are in and which country they are in. As we populate the list Cities that have zero landmarks linked to them should be omitted. Also, Countries, which have cities which have no landmarks should be omitted from the final result (as shown above).

I know how to group landmarks under the cities under the Muenchian method, but what throws me off the track is that I now need to group them under countries while committing them countries that do not have any cities or landmarks under them.

Can anybody point me at the right direction with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that as a grouping problem, rather you can use various keys to follow all those references:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="ref-city" match="cities/entry" use="linked-country/@link-id"/>
    <xsl:key name="ref-mark" match="landmarks/entry" use="linked-city/@link-id"/>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="countries/entry"
            />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="countries/entry">
        <xsl:variable name="cities" select="key('ref-city', @id)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="landmarks" select="key('ref-mark', $cities/@id)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$landmarks">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$cities"/>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cities/entry">
        <xsl:variable name="landmarks" select="key('ref-mark', @id)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$landmarks">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="city-name"/>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$landmarks"/>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="landmarks/entry">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="landmark-name"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```